# How much time passes on the Astral plane relative to the Material plane?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, planes, time

How much time passes on the Material plane while Astral Projecting?

From reading various wikis I have the impression that the Astral plane is timeless — time doesn't exist there. I imagine this would mean that to an Astral traveller, all points in time on the Material plane would be accessible somehow. That would effectively allow both infinitely-long “time outs” by hiding in the Astral plane, and allow them to go back to any point in time in their own past.

But maybe I'm missing something or misunderstanding what I've gleaned in my browsing. So, **how much time passes when and where? Does it matter if someone is on the Astral Plane or some other? How much time exactly — what's the ratio?**

Answer (score 10):

The very first sentence of the Timeless trait says this:

> On planes with this trait, **time still passes**, but the effects of time are diminished.

The Astral Plane's specific Timeless trait, in its entirety:

> Timeless. Age, hunger, thirst, poison, and natural healing don’t function in the Astral Plane, though they resume functioning when the traveler leaves the Astral Plane.

So time still passes at exactly the same rate as the Material Plane.

Comment: Well "dimished" is super relative. Could be anything like 100 years on the Astral Plane only equal to like 1ns on Earth.

Comment: @PatrickSchulze You need to do some reading. The Timeless trait slows or prevents aging, hunger and thirst. It has no effect on the flow of time.